# Converting nested dictionary into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
   {'data':[{'action_values': [
   {'action_type': 'offsite_conversion', 'value': '5479.8'},
   {'action_type': 'omni_add_to_cart', 'value': '9217.55'},
   {'action_type': 'omni_purchase', 'value': '5479.8'},
   {'action_type': 'add_to_cart', 'value': '9217.55'}]}]}
```

And I am trying to convert it where each element after action type is a pandas DataFrame column, and the value as row. Something like

```
  offsite_conversion    omni_add_to_cart    omni_purchase   add_to_cart
0   5479.8                9217.55               5479.8        9217.55
```

Comment: are there many rows of action_values in data? Something like: `pd.json_normalize(your_dict, ['data', 'action_values'])` is probably a good start

Answer (score 1):

Using .json_normalize():

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data=data["data"], record_path="action_values").transpose().reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Umm... not sure this gives a correct result?

Comment: how are you unsure? it either does or doesn't

Comment: Well, running this given the input, I get a dataframe with a header of what should be a row? (but I'm open to copy pasting it incorrectly or doing something stupid otherwise)

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(({'rowno': n, **ats} for n, ats in enumerate(data['data'])), 'action_values', meta='rowno').pivot_table(index='rowno', columns='action_type', values='value'))` might work though